# Flushing with \hfill under tabular (for resume template)

Tags: horizontal-alignment, resume

I am having trouble flushing the years all the way to the right on the same line with the company name. I tried /hfill but failed. I think my tabular format is actually not ideal to do so. Any suggestions to improve what I have below? It is a part of a resume template!!

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt,oneside]{article}
\begin{document}
        \noindent \begin{tabular}{@{} l l}
           \large{Internships}   & ABC Company \hfill 2020--Present\\
           & ABC Corp \hfill 2019-2020 \\
         & Non-profit \hfill 2018-2019\\
         \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would use `tabularx`, with 3 columns `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}ll >{\raggedleft}X@{}}`, or `{@{}lXr@{}}`.

Comment: Shifting the years to the far right makes the tabular very hard to read, IMO.

Comment: @Bernard hey thanks for the suggestion! It still doesn't work as I tried with your lXr suggestion :(

Comment: @campa hey thanks for the suggestion. I actually do need the years to flush all the way to right, not like the edge of the paper, but right up to the margin. I think the tabular setting isn't great. I tried with lXr suggestion by Bernard, but it still isn't doing so great...

Comment: Oh, so you mean that you want the years right-aligned?

Comment: @campa yes. So i would need the years to be all the way to the right while the company names all the way left.

Comment: All right, but then please rephrase the question a bit: both Bernard and me misunderstood the requirement, as you state "at the right (margin) _of the paper_".

Comment: @campa  done. Yeah I am trying to have the year appear all the way to the right on the same line with the firm name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx} 

\begin{document}

        \noindent \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} l Xr}
           \large{Internships} & ABC Company & 2020--Present\\
           & ABC Corp & 2019-2020 \\
         & Non-profit & 2018-2019\\
         \end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Bernard!!!